# How to make an array have the object type's methods?

Tags: kotlin

This question is to find out if something is possible with the language or not, and not about a specific problem or case.

I'm still learning the *dynamicness* and functional aspects of Kotlin.

---

Is there a way to turn this:

`for (item in myList) item.someMethod()`

into something like:

`myList.all().someMethod()`

Comment: Closest thing I can imagine is `myList.forEeach{ it.someMethod() }` - You probably can't call method directly on list object without implementing some kind of interface.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
data class MyObj(val v: String) {
    fun someMethod() {
        println(v)
    }
}

val myList = listOf(MyObj("A"), MyObj("B"), MyObj("C"))

for (item in myList) item.someMethod()
```

You can do something like this:

```
fun List<MyObj>.someMethod() {
    for (e in this) {
        e.someMethod()
    }
}

fun List<MyObj>.all() = this
```

It's a simple extension function on a list of a specific type.

If you need something like dynamic dispatch, thought, that would be impossible.

But maybe what you need is a Composite design pattern, where both the container and the elements implement the same interface. Something like this:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    fun someMethod()
}

class MyList(val elements: List<MyObj>) : SomeInterface {
    override fun someMethod() {
        for (e in elements) {
            e.someMethod()
        }
    }
}

data class MyObj(val v: String) : SomeInterface{
    override fun someMethod() {
        println(v)
    }
}
```

Will work similarly:

```
val myList = MyList(listOf(MyObj("A"), MyObj("B"), MyObj("C")))

myList.someMethod()
```

This pattern provides a nice contract between collection of elements and single element.

Comment: This is good, didn't think adding a function to a List of a specific type would work only for that type (didn't try either tho). But I'm more curious about adding a dynamic dispatch like you said, i.e. somehow dynamically add functions to List<T> if T is just an interface.

Comment: I expanded my answer with an example of how Composite design pattern could help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple.

```
myList.forEach { it.someMethod() }
// or
myList.forEach(Item::someMethod)
```

Extension function is possible too, but maybe that's too much already (at least narrow it down to your type):

```
fun List<Item>.someMethod() = forEach { it.someMethod() }
```

Or if you want to make accessing that method dependent on a specific receiver, you could also declare the extension function within that specific type. So given a type `MyObj` with the extension function as follows:

```
class MyObj {
  val funnyItems = mutableListOf<Item>()
  val usefulItems = mutableListOf<Item>()
  val whateverItems = mutableListOf<Item>()

  fun List<Item>.someMethod() = forEach { it.someMethod() }
}
```

it will only be callable if you have the appropriate receiver in place. So adding a function within class `MyObj` as follows, works:

```
fun callingSomeMethod() = funnyItems.someMethod() // no problem
```

but will not work outside of `MyObj`. E.g. consider a `main`-method not within `MyObj`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  listOf(MyObj())
    .forEach {
    // the following will not work... it is not accessible without appropriate receiver
    // it.funnyItems.someMethod() // doesn't compile...
      with(it) {
        // 'this' is now MyObj which is the required receiver in addition to List<Item>, so the following works:
        this.funnyItems.someMethod()
      }
    }
}
```